# Parse PFQueryTableViewController with innerQuery limit 1K +

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

Is it possible to have PFQueryTableViewController query with inner query limit that is bigger then 1000 entries.

I have this query

```
PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
        [activityQuery whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"Like"];
        [activityQuery whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:_user];
        [activityQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [activityQuery setLimit:1000];

        [query whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"postId" inQuery:activityQuery];
```

Pagination is working on main PFQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , it is not possible to fetch more than 1000 records at a single time.

You can do it by set the **Skip** and **limit** parameter in **PFQuery where clause**  with the help of recursive function to fetch records.

please refer this link for more info. [iOS Parse.com inner query doesn't fetch all objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605189/ios-parse-com-inner-query-doesnt-fetch-all-objects).

I hope this will help you.